# Unable to import tensorflow_hub getting error "cannot import name 'normalization' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers"

Tags: tensorflow, bert-language-model

I am trying to work on the bert tutorial in tensorflow https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/classify_text_with_bert

My pip list contains
`tensorboard 2.8.0`, `tensorboard-data-server 0.6.0`,`tensorboard-plugin-wit 1.8.0`,`tensorflow 2.8.0`,`tensorflow-addons 0.13.0`,`tensorflow-datasets 4.4.0`,`tensorflow-estimator 2.4.0`, `tensorflow-hub 0.12.0`,`tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.24.0`,`tensorflow-metadata 1.2.0`,`tensorflow-model-optimization 0.6.0`.

1. First error i get while importing tensorflow_hub is 'cannot import name 'normalization' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers'
2. Second error i get while running `bert_preprocess_model = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_preprocess)` is `name 'hub' is not defined`, however i think this is related to the first.

Python version is `Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32`

Can someone please help in solving this

Answer (score 0):

Solved, by creating new environment and doing fresh installations of tensorflow packages